# different lazy singletons in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, singleton, dart-null-safety

I saw these lazy singleton types in different projects, as far as I know, both are lazy singleton, the second one is better it's already final. But I'm curious about your opinions. What is the difference between them and what do you recommend to use them in different cases?

Thank you in advance.

```
// SINGLETON 1
class AppConstant1 {
  static late AppConstant1? _instance;
  AppConstant1._();

  static AppConstant1 instance() {
    _instance ??= AppConstant1._();
    return _instance!;
  }
}


// SINGLETON 2
class AppConstant2 {
  AppConstant2._();
  static final instance = AppConstant2._();
}
```

Comment: For `AppConstant1` is it necessary to have `late` with nullable?

Comment: I am not sure, I saw the `AppConstant1` example in a tutorial but personally, I use the second one.

Comment: I would suggest you use neither. Singleton is an anti-pattern. Use proper state management of your choice.

Comment: Could you please give me some more detailed information, I need that explanation.

Comment: @nvoigt I disagree that singletons are necessarily bad.  From another perspective, methods on a singleton are equivalent to freestanding functions except that they're associated with an object that could be mocked or faked for tests.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the first singleton pattern isn't even work:

```
// SINGLETON 1
class AppConstant1 {
  static late AppConstant1? _instance;
  AppConstant1._();

  static AppConstant1 instance() {
    _instance ??= AppConstant1._();
    return _instance!;
  }
}
```

it produces `Uncaught Error: LateInitializationError: Field '_instance' has not been initialized.` exception.
The reason for this is that :

```
_instance ??= AppConstant1._();
```

actually means

```
_instance = _instance ?? AppConstant1._();
```

In other words before assigning `_instance` we are reading `_instance` but `_instance` hasn't been initialized yet. Hence the error. So the code should be something like this:

```
class AppConstant1 {
  static AppConstant1? _instance;
  AppConstant1._();

  static AppConstant1 instance() {
    _instance ??= AppConstant1._();
    return _instance!;
  }
}
```

The main difference between first and second variants is that in first variant we could initialize singleton in particular moment and we can provide dependences as method arguments. That's it.